# Out Of Memory Exception when adding 3lakh rows in ASP DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

In my web application i want to show a table data in Data Grid for that i am using Entity Framework 4.0 while executing i am getting exception that out of memory.

Is there any limitation in ASP.NET Data Grid.
I am using Oracle DataBase.

Below is my code

```
        Entities obj = new Entities();
        GridView1.DataSource = obj.EQUIPMENTs.ToList();
        //Here i am getting exception
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you really need the `.ToList()`?

Comment: But still i am getting OutOfMemoryException

Answer (score 2):

You have to check your memory consumption. Use a [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for easy check. If you are in limits, chech the amount of data you load into the collection.

Remember that `CLR` apart of the allocated `RAM` limitation has a limitation on `LIst<T>` size, I see `obj.EQUIPMENTs.ToList()`. For `List<T>`, limitation is `2GB` (even on x64).

If one of these is true (or both), the solution is rearchitect your code.

Example:

It's hardly possible that your user need all that amount of data at once, may be you can slice it between different pages/tabs/whatever...

If you need some statistical information, some aggregation, or some calculation, do it on server and transfer only the results.

Comment: If you are on 4.5 with 64bit, then you can increase the list size with <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>.

Comment: But for Windows DataGridView it is hardly taking 2 min to dispaly all the records

Comment: @weismat: yes, but *it's better* do not do that. In 90% cases, there is other solution.

Comment: @Jagadesh: I have no any information about state of your apllicaiton. That's why I suggest you first check out memory and colleciton size you get, which can be and usually **is** a source of such kind of problems.